# Polynomial objects in any concrete category

Tags: ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, universal-algebra, abstract-nonsense

**EDIT: The original question had a trivial answer: it's just a coproduct. New question below**
**New Question:** *As shown below, in the category of commutative unital rings, the coproduct of a ring $R$ with $\mathbb Z\left[x\right]$ (which represents the forgetful functor to sets) is the polynomial ring $R\left[x\right]$. In what other concrete categories does the coproduct of an object $A$ with the object $Z$ ($Z$ is the object that represents the forgetful functor) give a useful construction.*

**Reformulating the question:** *When does the free object on the point in the co-slice category of maps $A\to B$ give a useful construction?* (from [giuseppe](https://mathoverflow.net/users/139854/giuseppe)'s comment below this question)

Given a ring (commutative, unital) $R$, the polynomial ring $R\left[x\right]$ is the initial pointed $R$-algebra, in the sense that given any other $R$-algebra $R\to A$ and a point $a\in A$ we have a unique $R$-algebra homomorphism $p\colon R\left[x\right]\to A$ such that $p\left(x\right)=a$.

Since the forgetful functor $\mathrm{CRing}\to\mathrm{Sets}$ is $\mathrm{Hom_{CRing}}\left(\mathbb Z\left[x\right],-\right)$ we can equivalenty think of $R\left[x\right]$ to be initial ring that is both an $R$-algebra and a $\mathbb Z\left[x\right]$-algebra. In diagrammatic form, we could say
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
R @>\iota>>R\left[x\right] @<x\mapsto x<<\mathbb Z\left[x\right]\\
@V \mathrm{id}_RVV @VV\exists! V @VV\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb Z\left[x\right]}V\\
R @>>\phi> A@<<a<\mathbb Z\left[x\right]
\end{CD}

I was thinking of this definition in any concrete category. So if I have a category $\mathcal C$ with a faithful functor $U\colon\mathcal C\to\mathrm{Sets}$ which is representable, that is $U\simeq\mathrm{Hom}_\mathcal C\left(Z,-\right)$ for some object $Z$ in $\mathcal C$. Then for any object $A$, we define the polynomial object $P$ over $A$ to be universal in the same sense as above, i.e.,

\begin{CD}
A @>\iota>>P_A @<f<<Z\\
@V \mathrm{id}_AVV @VV\exists! V @VV\mathrm{id}_ZV\\
A @>>\phi> Q@<<g<Z
\end{CD}
**EDIT: This is obviously a coproduct. Ignore the questions below.**
I was wondering what this would correspond to in other concrete categories with representable forgetful functors. I also wanted to know some example of this construction in other categories. Are these 'polynomial objects' things that already have names in other specific categories?

Comment: I don't quite understand your diagram but wouldn't it just be the coproduct of Z with A (assuming co products exist).

Comment: @Asvin Obviously. Stupid me. I got carried away. Yes of course you're right. My brain seems to be down.

Comment: Someone should write a CW answer and Chetan can accept it, to keep this Q off the 'unanswered' list.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I have edited the question and replaced it by a new question that came up.

Comment: In the category of associative rings, you could take $P_A$ as the free associative ring $\mathbb{Z}\langle x\rangle$, $A$ an associative algebra, and then you obtain $A \langle x \rangle$. In the category of non-unitary non-associative algebras (without any assumption), a similar thing happens. I guess that for certain varieties of algebras (I cannot be precise though) your question leads to an interesting construction.

Comment: So the new question is when the free object on the point in the co-slice category of maps  $A \to B$ gives a useful construction?

Comment: @giuseppe Yes. Exactly. Though that assumes that $U\colon\mathcal C\to\mathrm{Sets}$ has an adjoint (which is usually the case). You know any example of this construction? But more generally, it's the coproduct with the object representing $U$.

Comment: If  $U$ is representable then it has a left adjont $F,$ since the representing object of $U$ has the universal property of the free object on the point and then for every other set $A$ you build $F(A)$ as $\sqcup_{A}F(*)$

Comment: @giuseppe Yes. I'll just add that as a reformulation in the question.

Comment: I think your question is too broad to have an answer. 

You are just taking the composition of two left adjoints; you have the left adjoint to your functor $U$ and then you compose it with the left adjoint to the forgetful functor $(A \to B ) \mapsto B$, which is just given by taking the coproduct with $A$. So, a stupid answer would be that this is useful whenever the category of maps $A \to B$ is interesting.